# Change inner user control in Silverlight/WPF by a property at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I am creating some custom user controls for WPF. This user controls contain custom dependency properties so I can fill them in the designer.

One of this properties is called "InnerUserControlType". This dependency proeprty is a custom enumeration containing some values like TextBox, ComboBox, Label, CheckBox, etc.

I would like to be able to set this property in my XAML pages in the designer and then see the user control change the displayed inner control depending on the property.

How should I implement this? The grid which will contain the inner control in my user control is a normal field, so it cannot be accessed from a static method property (like the dependency properties).

I want it to have it working in the designer so the designers can work easily.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The pattern in Silverlight is to have containers that can contain any type of control (as content or via data/item templates). Why are you hardwiring it so that it only contains fixed controls? That seems to be taking control away from the designers. Can you show a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `ContentControl` in the grid, bind the `Content` property to the `UserControl` via relative source

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAnsector,
                                  AncestorType={x:Tyle myNamespace:MyControl}}}"
```

and make a `DataTemplateSelector` that will check the value of `InnerUserControlType` and will return an appropriate data template containing the control that was asked for in the property.

Depending on your scenarios, you might need to make sure the controls in the data template have the right data context. If the data context of the controls should be the same as of the user control, then on the root element in the data template, add relative binding for data context. Something like (for the text box data template):

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAnsector,
                               AncestorType={x:Tyle myNamespace:MyControl}}}"
 ......
</TextBox>
```

#### EDIT:

I've noticed only the wpf tag and missed the silverlight one.
In Silverlight you don't have `...TemplateSelector` properties, so use a converter instead.